# Why won't Menendez kill Mason at the beginning of Odysseus?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Storyline wise, on the mission Odysseus, why won't Menendez kill Mason?

Are they related?  Or did something happen in Black Ops I didn't get?

Comment: Use >! in front of your text

Comment: It's all well and good putting masked spoilers in the question body, but you've put it in the title which isn't masked and people can see...

Comment: You don't need to hide spoilers, especially by making the title vague.  If people care about spoilers, they should not be reading questions on a Q&A site.

Comment: I disagree with @OrigamiRobot you should use the spoiler formatting if your Question body text contains spoilers, why else would they exist? I like reading questions and answers about games I'm currently playing, in fact even more so than games I have already played and completed. Maybe this should be a meta discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Menendez wants Mason to suffer like he did after his sister, the sole driving force of his life, was killed.

Answer (score 0):

After I beat the campaign, I logged in next day and another video plays. It shows David as a kid, saving Josefina from the fire.

So may thats why he doesnt want to kill him.